# Column sum of Opencv Matrix elements

Tags: opencv, matrix, sum

I need to compute sum of elements in all columns separately.

Now I'm using:

Matrix cross_corr should be summed.

```
Mat cross_corr_summed;
for (int i=0;i<cross_corr.cols;i++)                                                     
    {
        double column_sum=0;
        for (int k=0;k<cross_corr.rows;k++)
        {
            column_sum +=cross_corr.at<float>(k,i);             
        }
        cross_corr_summed.push_back(column_sum);
    }
```

The problem is that my program takes quite a long time to run. This is one of parts that is suspicious to cause this. 
Can you advise any possible faster implementation???

Thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sum of each column opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097416/sum-of-each-column-opencv)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need a [cv::reduce](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce):

```
cv::reduce(cross_corr, cross_corr_summed, 0, CV_REDUCE_SUM, CV_32S);
```

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#sum  `cv::sum` is simpler.

Comment: `cv::sum` can not be applied along a specific dimension

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your data is continuous and single-channeled, you can access the matrix data directly:

```
int width = cross_corr.cols;
float* data = (float*)cross_corr.data;
Mat cross_corr_summed;
for (int i=0;i<cross_corr.cols;i++)
{
    double column_sum=0;
    for (int k=0;k<cross_corr.rows;k++)
    {
        column_sum += data[i + k*width];
    }
    cross_corr_summed.push_back(column_sum);
}
```

which will be faster than your use of `.at_<float>()`. In general I avoid the use of `.at()` whenever possible because it is slower than direct access.

Also, although `cv::reduce()` (suggested by Andrey) is much more readable, I have found it is slower than even your implementation in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mat originalMatrix;    
Mat columnSum;    
for (int i = 0; i<originalMatrix.cols; i++)    
     columnSum.push_back(cv::sum(originalMatrix.col(i))[0]);
```

Comment: Its not as good as cv::reduce(). Still, I tried to avoid the multiple use of for loop, and also the use of .at<>.