# Matrix Multiplication in OpenCV - Combining cv::Mat and cv::Scalar Objects

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am trying to implement different cross-correlation algorithms in C++ using some OpenCV library functions. At some point, I need to take the sum of the rows and columns of my matrix. I am using cv::Mat as my matrix class and I am comfortable as a beginner to do some basic matrix operations in with cv::Mat. My only problem is I am experienced in MATLAB, which is really good in this kind of minor things. So, I will put my requirements in terms of MATLAB code (apologies in advance if someone doesn't understand MATLAB). What I am after is this:

IN MATLAB, For example

```
gg = [1 1 1; 2 2 2; 3 3 3; 4 4 4]; % is a 4x3 matrix

sumGrows = (gg,1); % Sum of all rows - will be [10 10 10]; 1 means DIMENSION=ROWS
sumGcols = (gg,2); % Sum of all columns - [3; 6; 9; 12]; 2 means DIMENSION=COLUMNS
```

FYI, In MATLAB, a comment is noted with a %

How can I do that in OpenCV? I know that there is a function called "sum" in OpenCV, but that doesn't return a cv::Mat object. Do I need to do some static/dynamic casting then? AFAIK, the return type of sum() is Scalar. Please point me to the right direction.

FYI, I am not a student! I am professional (used to be in Java-based Development and Systems Engineering). But currently taking over a project where I have to do C++ based implementation.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [cv::reduce](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce) for summing rows or cols.

See also this question: [Column sum of Opencv Matrix elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833657/column-sum-of-opencv-matrix-elements)

Comment: Thanks for the nudge! I wish I could give you a +1 for not being annoyed (visibly) by my dumb questions! Sorry I am new so no reputation to vote yet :(

To make it less dumb, do you have any recommended website that provides tutorials on OpenCV (besides Willow Garage)?

Comment: OpenCV has its own site http://opencv.org/ You can find the latest news, official tutorials and documentation there.

Comment: +1, been using opencv for a while now, but had never noticed `cv::reduce`!

Comment: Thanks guys for not dumping me as an amateur! Someone gave me a low reputation last time and I had to create a new account to post my problems!! Thanks for all your positive comments!!

Comment: @AndreyKamaev  cv::reduce is not working and complaining that there is a type mismatch! but my source and destination types are both unsigned char so what could be the problem?